# Patent US640598A

Tags: tools

[image]

What is the value of this.. I can only find drawings of it and it says it was never produced but I have one

Comment: Can you please clarify your question. The patent expired approx 100 years ago.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is not [on topic](https://patents.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site.

Answer (score 1):

The picture shows only half of the Tool, the patent  [US 640,598](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/3d/1f/63/f27df8d785aca6/US640598.pdf) describes the invention was a tool useful in the building of wire fences, as well as the other specific uses.

Comment: Actually, I think the picture shows the whole tool. It is just you can't see the bottom handle from that angle. It has to be there since the split claw end is part of the bottom handle.

Answer (score 0):

[US640598A](https://patents.google.com/patent/US640598A/en?oq=US640598A) Describes a combination tool particularly useful for fencing. This diagram is from the patent:

[image]

First claim is as follows:

> 1. A tool comprising a member having a head, the head provided with a longitudinally centrally arranged web and constituting
>      clamping shoulders extending transversely of the web, a member having
>      its inner end provided with parallel jaws receiving between them the
>      said web, and having a pivotal connection between the jaws and the web
>      at a point intermediate its ends, the web having a cutter-opening, one
>      of said jaws having a cutter-opening adapted to cooperate therewith
>      and the jaw at the opposite side of the web cut away to prevent
>      engagement with the wire being cut, substantially as described.

The arms (a) would be useful for prying out nails and the cutting jays (F, H & H) would be used for cutting wire. There are other features that provide additional utility.

The patent would have expired roughly in 1917. As for value, the patent has no current residual value although it constitutes prior art. If you are asking about collectable value of your tool, that would be off topic for this site.